# how to Access buttons from another form in c#

Tags: c#

I have two forms. I have a button in mainForm. When i clicked button1 the main form will show and the button1 will be Enabled false. Now i want to Enable it to True when my ChildForm gets Close. PLease help me .
My code For Enable= False is

```
        CstmersFrm cstFm = new CstmersFrm();
        cstFm.MdiParent = this;
        cstFm.Show();
        cstFm.BringToFront();
        btnCstmr.Enabled = false;
```

Iam trying to Enable= True is In cstmersFrm _Closed Event

```
        mFrm = (mainForm)this.MdiParent;
        mFrm.btnCstmr.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: How about using `delegates`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register to the child form Closed event on the main form:

```
        Form child = new Form();
        child.MdiParent=this;
        child.Show();
        child.FormClosed+=child_FormClosed;
```

and then set the button to Enabled:

```
void child_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
     btnCstmr.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Sir Iam getting error as 
Error 1 The name 'cstFm_FormClosed' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You haven't created the event handler in the Main form. You can easily create it by typing cstFm.FormClosed+= and hit tab twice, it will create the event handler for you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your questions as answered, as it benefits both you and the people who helped you. (Feel free to do so on other answered questions you have on the site) Thanks!